# How to sum COUNT values

Tags: sql, sqlite, counting

I'm very new to SQLite so please forgive me asking something stupid.
From a database with a table containing aircraft data I can count the records with data from a manufacturer with my existing query:

```
SELECT Manufacturer, COUNT(Manufacturer) AS Number
FROM aircraft
WHERE Manufacturer like 'Airbus%'
GROUP BY Manufacturer
ORDER BY COUNT(Manufacturer) DESC;
```

This gives me

```
Manufacturer        Number
Airbus              3473
Airbus Military     29
Airbus Helicopters  2
```

Is there a way to get the calculated grand total (3504) in the results without removing the 'GROUP BY'clause?
I can't get SUM() and TOTAL() to work. The questions about this counting an aggregating seem to use values found in the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT Manufacturer, COUNT(Manufacturer) AS Number
  FROM aircraft
  WHERE Manufacturer like 'Airbus%'
  GROUP BY Manufacturer
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Total', COUNT(Manufacturer)
  FROM aircraft
  WHERE Manufacturer like 'Airbus%'
) t
ORDER BY Manufacturer = 'Total', Number DESC
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o1qpRP1ZgQH3Aken5FPYPc/0).
Or with a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Manufacturer, COUNT(Manufacturer) AS Number
  FROM aircraft
  WHERE Manufacturer like 'Airbus%'
  GROUP BY Manufacturer  
)  
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM cte
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Total', SUM(Number) FROM cte
) t  
ORDER BY MAnufacturer = 'Total', Number DESC
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o1qpRP1ZgQH3Aken5FPYPc/1).